# Multiple keyshape animations in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, shape-keys

I would like to know how to make two or more keyshapes animate/run in the BGE? For example, I have a face and want to move the left or right eyebrow, or both, by calling the two keyshapes animations or running pre-made animations in the shape key editor. 
If possible please show me how to do this in a python module. 
I tried to juggle with setting priorities, but that seemed a little cumbersome as you then have to put in delays to wait for animations to finish playing and it gets complicated...
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the number of shapekeys that can be played over each there is limited to the number of layers in BGE. This forum post makes it clearer: [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?246315-mulitple-shapkeys-with-the-action-actuaor-in-the-bge)

Comment: It seems the best method is to use bone driven animation of shape keys... Anyone have any tutorials or videos for blender 2.69?? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Search youtube for 'blender shapekey driver' and you'll get several choices. I don't think anything has changed for some time that would invalidate any driver tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I have already looked at a few, struggling to find one that allows me to use Drivers that take variables from python scripts to control the values of shapekey properties. I want to use a script/python module that allows the driver, using an F-Curve,to read the value of the codes' Driver Value and sets the value of the selected property (that being the shapekeys' value) it was assigned to. I found this [link] (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers) with some info but it is not clear enough for me to implement. Noob, Thanks though!

Comment: When you keyframe a value you specify that on frame 10 the value will be .34 - when you use a driver you specify a calculation that is used to decide what value is used at any given time, the driver returns one value, you specify how to calculate that value. The second image on that manual page show that the x-rotation of bone f3 is the value that is returned by the driver. You can also use python (scripted expression) to calculate the value - maybe something like ylocation/4.

Comment: Blender Versi 2.76 can do that.
There is in Drop Sheet
And the way is same as you make action bge